# How to insert array values from XML into each sequencial cell of row in Excel, loop for each row?

Tags: excel, xml, powershell

I have an XML file that contains a value for each hour of a given day for a given month.

Example, the start date/time will be 15th at 12:00 am of the given month and end date/time will be 15th at 12:00 am of the next month.

Example of XML file:

```
<Generated>
<Entry>
    <ID>76492055</ID>
    <Date>2018-09-15</Date>
    <Time>00:00:00</Time>
    <Income>746557.0993</Income>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>76492055</ID>
    <Date>2018-09-15</Date>
    <Time>01:00:00</Time>
    <Income>815445.5908</Income>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>76492055</ID>
    <Date>2018-09-15</Date>
    <Time>02:00:00</Time>
    <Income>1190228.1310</Income>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>76492055</ID>
    <Date>2018-09-15</Date>
    <Time>03:00:00</Time>
    <Income>932243.0268</Income>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>76492055</ID>
    <Date>2018-09-15</Date>
    <Time>04:00:00</Time>
    <Income>709702.1181</Income>
</Entry>
...
</Generated>
```

I can most certainly display the data fine with the following code in PowerShell:

```
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "TheXMLFile.xml")

[datetime]$EndDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).ToString("yyyy-MM-15")
[datetime]$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-15")

$IncomeDates = 0..(($EndDate - $StartDate).days-1) | % { 
$StartDate.AddDays($_).ToShortDateString() }

foreach ($IncomeDate in $IncomeDates) { 
    $xml.Generated.Entry | Where {$_.Date -eq $IncomeDate} | Select ID,Date,Time,Income
}
```

However, I need to have PowerShell extract the XML data for the given day (per hour) of that month and insert into each sequential cell in that row (of that day) in the target Excel worksheet.

Example of the target worksheet:

[image: Target worksheet]

Comment: Does the spreadsheet have the top row already in it, or is it a blank spreadsheet? Does it have the left column already populated?

Comment: You could use Doug Finkes `Export-Excel` to build a pivot table.

Comment: Thank you, both solutions work great! I am using @TheMadTechnician's method currently for multiple "copy-paste" operations, however, I had to tweak it somewhat to paste into respective static ranges. Sometimes an error is thrown about **unable to paste**, but seems to work when I clear out the clipboard with: `Set-Clipboard $Null` and pause for a short while: `Start-Sleep -Seconds 4` before pasting the new/next selection (from an XML file with additional data) in a `foreach` loop. Otherwise, these are two great solutions and I can certainly use these for different scenarios, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the top row and left column already in the spreadsheet this will read the XML, open the spreadsheet, read the date range, create an array of objects based off that date range, populate the data from the XML, and then paste it into the spreadsheet.

```
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "TheXMLFile.xml")

$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $XL.workbooks.open('C:\Path\To\Spreadsheet.xls')
$DateRange = $WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Item(1).Cells|% Text|Select -skip 1

# Create a hashtable representing a blank day
$BlankDay = [ordered]@{}
0..23|ForEach{$Blankday.Add(("{0}:00:00" -f "$_".Padleft(2,'0')),$null)}

# Build Hashtable to track all days as objects based off the blank day hashtable
$DataHash = [ordered]@{}
$DateRange | ForEach-Object{ $DataHash.add($_,[pscustomobject]$BlankDay) }

# Update each day with data from the XML
$xml.Generated.Entry | Where{$_.date -in $DateRange} | ForEach-Object {
    $DataHash[$_.Date]."$($_.Time)" = $_.Income
}
# Convert the data to a tab delimited CSV, skipping the header row, and copy it to the clipboard
$DataHash.Values|convertto-csv -del "`t" -notype|Select -Skip 1 | clip
# Paste it into cell B2
$WB.ActiveSheet.Rows.Item(2).Cells.Item(2).PasteSpecial()
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code and expanding the foreach:

```
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "TheXMLFile.xml")

[datetime]$EndDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).ToString("yyyy-MM-15")
[datetime]$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-15")

$IncomeDates = 0..(($EndDate - $StartDate).days-1) | % { 
$StartDate.AddDays($_).ToShortDateString() }

$Data = foreach ($IncomeDate in $IncomeDates) { 
    $xml.Generated.Entry | Where {$_.Date -eq $IncomeDate} | Select ID,Date,Time,Income
}

$Data|Export-excel .\TheExcelfile.xlsx -IncludePivotTable  -PivotRows "Date" -PivotColumns "Time" -PivotData @{"InCome"="Sum"} -Sh
```

Yields based on your sample data:

[image]

Comment: My German Excel expecting a decimal comma cripples the values.

Comment: Your english is excellent, I would have never guessed that you were not a native speaker.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Reading/writing here helps a lot to brush up my skills not only in English ;-)